# Spring componentscan for multiple packages

Tags: spring

I want Spring to perform dependency injection from 2 different projects and have a main @Configuration annotated class as below -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(value = { "com.x.y", "com.a.b" })
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Classes under com.x.y is part of packages which contains AppConfig class but classes under com.a.b are part of different jar which is packaged under war file containing AppConfig class.

When i am deploying war file i am getting error as -

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of 
type [com.a.b.c.d.ClassA]: No qualifying bean of type [com.a.b.c.d.ClassA] 
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire 
candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
```

I am not sure what is wrong in my way of using @ComponentScan. Looking for inputs from Spring experts.

Thanks

Comment: Use this @ComponentScan(basePackages = {'package1','package2'}

Comment: Its not helping out. I would like to add that package2 is part of another jar file. Can this be still done.

Comment: Ya... did you include another jar into your project?? Either via maven or manually?? It needs to be there so that you can use it

Comment: Yes, i have a .war file which contains the jar file - containing package 2. But its giving same exceptions

Comment: How are you creating a bean??

Comment: using @Autowired annotation on a constructor

Comment: That doesn’t sound correct!! That how you inject beans, not  bean.. with scancomponent, you it scans classes marked with @component and child, may be ClassA has not been marked component in jar your are importing, would you mind looking into that?

Comment: Would you mind sharing annotation on ClassA??

Comment: Class is annotated with Service annotation as - Service public class classA { @Autowired public ClassA (final ClassB classB) }

Comment: looks good! I am working on a similar module, but it is working fine here

Comment: is there anyway i can debug if Spring is really doing component scanning as it supposed to ?

Comment: Not in my knowledge!! Sorry!